# Error with displaying div inside grid cell

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Trying to figure out why div with `class="input-group form-fieldset_select"` is not inside grid cell, but lower then it.

```css
.form-fieldset {
  width: 290px;
  height: auto;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 20px 56px;
  row-gap: 8px;
}
.form-fieldset > legend {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.input-group {
  grid-row: 2/3;
  display: flex;
}

.form-fieldset_select {
  justify-content: center;
}

.select-button-label {
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
  width: 128px;
  height: 56px;
  border: 1px solid gold;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

.select-button-label > input {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="form-fieldset">
  <legend>Legend</legend>
   <div class="input-group form-fieldset_select">
    <label class="select-button-label">
      Button1
      <input type="text" />
    </label>
     <label class="select-button-label">
       Button2
      <input type="text" />
    </label>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the [W3](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#edef-FIELDSET) guideline for the fieldset and legend, `<legend>` should be the first child of fieldset.

In your case you have done correctly by placing `<legend>` as a first child and after that your `<div class="input-group form-fieldset_select">`.

If you want that div inside grid cell than you have to change your structure by replacing `<fieldset>` tag with `<div>`.